# Manage users for SAAS applications in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, saas

I am working on a SAAS application wherein I want to provide a SSO to our users. We have concept of clients and users. `Client` is the main admin user who registered and `Users` table store the users created by the main `Client`. A main Client can create multiple sub-users under their account. The main client becomes the Admin user while all sub-users become Normal users.

The problem arises when a normal user also registers as a new admin user. In this scenario we have 2 users with same email addresses but different roles and different ClientIDs. I can have a solution to this asking user to login either as Admin or Normal User on Login page, but I don't want to do so. A sample table representation is shown below -

```
Username    Role      ClientID
--------    ----      --------
u1@e.com    Admin        1
u2@e.com    Normal       1
u3@e.com    Normal       1
u2@e.com    Admin        2
u3@e.com    Normal       2
```

In the above table, when `u1@e.com` tries to login, there is no problem as it is an Admin user. When `u2@e.com` tries to login, the system is confused as to login like Normal for ClientID 1 or as Admin for ClientID 2.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  user will have to specify which Client (Tenant) they want to log into.  One way to do this is to have each client access the system using a different URL.  So they go to

```
https://Client1.myapp.net/login
```

or

```
https://myapp.net/Client1/login
```

Or you present a bit of UI for the user to pick the client when the email is registered in both.

Comment: the application is hosted on a single domain, so no domain level changes are there. 1 application, 1 code, 1 domain and this scenario. 100 tenants using 1 software

Comment: But will that be the case forever?  You might want to plan for a future where there are multiple versions of your app in production, and multiple instances for different tenants.   But even so, you're in complete control of the path portion of the url, and can still use that.

Comment: makes sense @David. Another question I have, what if I have to make these users login to 2 different SAAS application, shall I put the client and users table in a separate tables and provide SSO for both applications?